# No definition found for exported static routine : .main(String args[])

Tags: blackberry

we are executing of my .cod and .jad files on Blackberry JDE4.0.2 simulator7290. while building that project we are geting the folloewing warnings

```
Deleting C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.0.2\samples\com\rim\samples\device\BlackCard\BlackCard.cod.
Building BlackCard ...
C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.0.2\bin\rapc.exe  -quiet import=..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\net_rim_api.jar codename=BlackCard BlackCard.rapc "C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.0.2\1[1].1\1.1\BlackCard.cod" "C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.0.2\1[1].1\1.1\BlackCard.jad"
Warning!: No entry points found
Warning!: No definition found for exported static routine: .main(String[])
BlackCard - no errors.
Build complete.
```

Comment: It says you don't have a main method, I assume you do actually have a main method included somewhere in the project right?

Answer (score 3):

I´ve searched in many forums to resolve this problem. But found out a easy way to create a new BlackBerry Project without this Problem.

I have the Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.0 includes BlackBerry SDK.

**Answer:**

1. Create BlackBerry project: (Menu) File->New->BlackBerry Project
2. Enter a project name.
3. Click "next".
4. Under the source tab window open "Details" 
   (if it is not open, click the arrow besides "Details")
5. **Click "Add project '...' to build path"**
6. Click "finish".

This works for me and I hope for you too ;)

Sorry for my english.

André Müller

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of context here - but it really looks like you dont have a main defined in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this support forum thread:
[No definition found for exported static routine: .main(String[])](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/No-definition-found-for-exported-static-routine-main-String/m-p/238814)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using an old JDK version, and was hit by this error. I would not mark this as solved. I am still trying to figure out how to change my class path, ala http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/No-definition-found-for-exported-static-routine-main-String/td-p/238814 "The reason was a misconfigured bin-path in the eclipse classpath. Eclipse generated the classfiles in an other location than the rapc compiler searched for them. Fixing the classpath did it. " Admittedly I am using BBEclipse on a mac :/

Comment: refactoring the project name and package name seemed to help